# Access IWebHost in AWS Lambda?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, .net-core-3.1

I'm using .net core 3.1 with AWS lambda ( not serverless lambda, but a pure regular lambda).

I want to use Nlog as the logger library.

In a serverless lambda ( or a regular .net core project) , I could do this via :

```
 public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args) 
                .UseStartup<Startup>() 
                .UseNLog()   //< -------here
                .Build();
```

But in simple aws lambda , I don't have `IWebHost` . All I have is:

```
FunctionHandler(object input, ILambdaContext context)  
{
 ...
}
```

**Question:**

How can I access `IWebHost`  inside a regular aws lambda?

Comment: It sounds very much as if `IWebHost` simply doesn't exist in this context.

Comment: @Llama [in another aws lambda ( serverless lambda) there is access to it](https://i.imgur.com/o8u7KVD.jpg)

Comment: But you're creating it there... and effectively hosting a full ASP.NET Core application on AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only access the IWebHost if you're using the lambda aspnet library.

https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer/README.md

Av